# Device Recovery tool cannot detect phone

Tags: insider-preview, soft-reset, recovery-tool, flash-memory

I am using Lumia 720 and I tried to install Windows 10 unsuccessfully.

My phone has now bricked, leaving reflashing as the only option left.

My phone is connected to the laptop via a USB Cable but the recovery tool fails to detect it. I have done a soft reset and then held the volume key up till the lightning icon and gear appeared. Currently the phone (with a lightning icon and gear on screen) is connected to laptop but the recovery tool just fails to detect phone.

I have restarted my laptop and phone numerous times. Please help